# Why does libusb_open always returns LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, libusb-1.0, openocd

I am trying to use OpenOCD on Windows 8 with x64 architecture. I installed WinUSB driver via Zadig. I tried to run OpenOCD with administrator privileges, and also I disabled Windows 8 driver signature enforcement during WinUSB installation. Whenever I attempted to run the program, libusb_open returns LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED (-12).

How can I run libusb-1.0 on Windows 8 properly?

P.S.: Incidentally I also tried same configuration with Windows 7 x64, and OpenOCD just works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your device is a USB composite device (like recent STM32 devboards with ST-LINKv2 dongles?)

On Zadig, uncheck "Options::Ignore Hubs or Composite Parents" and see if your target device has composite parent or not.

If it is so, then that probably is a Windows8/libusb-1.0 limitation.

@see http://www.emblocks.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=478

You might want to try attaching WinUSB to composite parent as stated on libusb-1.0 site: http://www.libusb.org/wiki/windows_backend .

> "It is however possible to replace the composite parent driver with WinUSB to access the device."

But this means ALL composite devices gets WinUSB attached, which could be a source of other issues.

Comment: I am trying to program/debug Stellaris LM4F120 LaunchPad Evaluation Board via OpenOCD.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was trying to use a FT2232H chip which came up as a composite device, but didn't know there was an option in Zadig to show composite devices. After installing libusbk onto the composite device, it didn't replace the driver for ALL composite devices - just that device. So perhaps this is a valid solution.

Comment: Thanks! Installing libusbK on composite device finally solved issues with OpenOCD and USB Blaster on Win10